# Audio devices no longer appear in Sounds

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I was messing with pactl and alsa and managed to disable all sounds on my computer. The devices don't show up.

I've reinstalled both packages as well as linux-sound-base, rebooted; nothing.

I do see the device in `aplay -l`:

```
> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: 92HD75B3X5 Analog [92HD75B3X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I'm figuring that's the speakers, but I'm not sure how to detect the microphone.

Advice on how to repair sound to original settings would be appreciated.

The devices list in the Sounds GUI program is empty, both for input and output.

In response to comment, here's the resume of `amixer contents`:

```
> amixer contents
numid=30,iface=CARD,name='Dock Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=34,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=40,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=46,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=8 Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=29,iface=CARD,name='Headphone Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=25,iface=CARD,name='Internal Mic Phantom Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=27,iface=CARD,name='Line Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=26,iface=CARD,name='Mic Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=28,iface=CARD,name='Speaker Phantom Jack'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=127,step=0
  : values=119
  | dBscale-min=-95.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=1
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=127,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-95.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=1
numid=55,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0
  : values=255,255
  | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=on,on
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=15,step=0
  : values=4,4
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=15,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=0
numid=35,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=41,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=1
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=47,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=2
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=36,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=42,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=1
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=48,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=2
  ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=37,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
  ; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=43,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=1
  ; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x82 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x02]
numid=49,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=2
  ; type=IEC958,access=rw--l---,values=1
  : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x82 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x02]
numid=38,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=44,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=50,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=2
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
  ; Item #0 'Disabled'
  ; Item #1 'Enabled'
  : values=1
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Bass Speaker Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0
  | dBscale-min=-18.00dB,step=6.00dB,mute=0
numid=56,iface=MIXER,name='Digital Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=120,step=0
  : values=60,60
  | dBscale-min=-30.00dB,step=0.50dB,mute=0
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Internal Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=0
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
  ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
  ; Item #0 'Internal Mic'
  ; Item #1 'Mic'
  ; Item #2 'Line'
  : values=0
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Internal Mic Boost Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Internal Mic Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Internal Mic Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
  : values=off,off
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=127,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=-95.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=1
numid=32,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
amixer: Control default element read error: Invalid argument

numid=31,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=4,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0,0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR,RL,RR

numid=33,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR

numid=39,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3
  ; type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0
  : values=
numid=52,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  | container
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR

numid=45,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=7
  ; type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0
  : values=
numid=53,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=7
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  | container
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR

numid=51,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=8
  ; type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0
  : values=
numid=54,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=8
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=3,4,5,6,7,8,0,0
  | container
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR
```

Alsamixer screenshot:

[image: screenshot of alsamixer]

Comment: The internal sound device is there. What did you expect to see?

Comment: @CL i can't see it in the Sounds program. But more importantly, it doesn't play any sound.

Comment: Does `aplay something.wav` or `aplay -D plughw something.wav` work?

Comment: @CL. neither work

Comment: Silence, or error message?

Comment: @CL. Just silence

Comment: What is the output of `amixer contents`?

Comment: @CL. edited question to include

Comment: Try enabling the "Speaker Playback" switch.

Comment: @CL. how would I do that?

Comment: Run `alsamixer`.

Comment: @CL. I did, I don't know where that switch is.

Comment: If it shows PulseAudio, press F6 to select the hardware device. There should be a playback control named "Speaker"; select it and press "M" to unmute.

Comment: @CL. I don't see the option, and trying the different Sound Cards didn't fix it. I will add a screenshot to the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the [Pulse Audio Volume Control](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio) and seeing if the device shows up?

Comment: I have pulseaudio installed. Not sure what program I'm supposed to open. Running `pulseaudio` says "Daemon already running". However `pulseaudio --check` shows nothing.